# How to Remove Child without error Child must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I've got a problem that I can't figure out.

I've got in my Engine Class (engine.as) this :

```
public static var viseur:Viseur;

var lookCocoDessous:Boolean = thisBack == "cocotierDessous";
if (lookCocoDessous) {
     viseur = new Viseur(stage);
    stage.addChild(viseur);
    viseur.visible = true;
    souris.visible = false;
    puzzle.addListeners();

}
```

And in my puzzle class (Puzzle.as) this :

```
public static var viseur:Viseur;
```

and when the function "backToJardin" is called I want to remove "viseur" (which has been called in the Engine.as). 
So I wrote this :

```
public function backToJardin(thisBack:String):void{

    Engine.viseur.stage.removeChild(viseur);
        Engine.newBack = "jardin";
    stageRef.dispatchEvent(new Event("changeBackground"));

    }
```

But I've got this error :

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca::Puzzle/backToJardin()

Do you know why ? And how can I resolve it ?

I'd like to remove COMPLETELY "viseur" when the function is called in my Puzzle.as (it will never be called again, so I want to "destroy" it)

Thank you for your help,

---

EDIT

I've try to put

`Engine.removeViseur();`

in my backToJardin function

and put

`public function removeViseur(){ 
stage.removeChild(viseur);}`

in my Engine class, but I've got this error : error 1061 removeViseur can not be defined through a reference with static type

(and same thing for that in my Engine.as class) :

```
public function removeViseur(){
            if (Engine.viseur && Engine.viseur.parent)
 {
       Engine.viseur.parent.removeChild(viseur);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove viseur in Engine, try this

```
  if (Engine.viseur && Engine.viseur.parent)
 ｛
       Engine.viseur.parent.removeChild(viseur);
  ｝
```

Or put this code in a function in Engine, and call the function in backToJardin.

**EDIT**

The function in engine should be static.

```
public static function removeViseur()
{

    if (viseur && viseur.parent)
    {
        viseur.parent.removeChild(viseur);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Same error : Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null... Any idea why ?

Comment: I've try to put Engine.removeViseur(); in my backToJardin function  and put public function removeViseur(){ stage.removeChild(viseur);}  in my Engine class, but I've got this error : error 1061 removeViseur can not be defined through a reference with static type.

Comment: Same thing, of course, for public function removeViseur(){
   if (Engine.viseur && Engine.viseur.parent)
 {
       Engine.viseur.parent.removeChild(viseur);
  }
 }

Comment: Can't find the solution. been searching for hours now... Anyone could help me ?

Comment: Thank you. It seems, at first, to work as the child "viseur" is no longer visible. But if I drag my mouse on a text or if I drag it out of the screen and come back, the child "viseur" is here again ! Is there absolutely no way to destroy it completely ? (here's a small video : http://ul.to/asdj7931  (1.3Mb)

Comment: If you are sure the removeViseur  function was called and viseur was removed， and the viseur  appears again,try to set a breakpoint in the code where viseur  is created and added to stage.Or anywhere else you may add viseur to stage.